# How can i make wordpress blog pagination like this?

Tags: wordpress, pagination, blogs, custom-wordpress-pages

How can i make my wordpress blog pagination like this image below:
[image]

So that it will show page number as "Page (number)" and arrow sign is for next and previous blog page.

Please help me

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

posting answer for badge.
the function used to get pagination is the following. The parameters set with have only current page number preceeded by 'PAGE'

```
$args = array(
    'base'               => '%_%',
    'format'             => '?paged=%#%',
    'total'              => 1,
    'current'            => 0,
    'show_all'           => false,
    'end_size'           => 1,
    'mid_size'           => 1,
    'prev_next'          => true,
    'prev_text'          => __('<'),
    'next_text'          => __('>'),
    'type'               => 'plain',
    'add_args'           => false,
    'add_fragment'       => '',
    'before_page_number' => 'PAGE',
    'after_page_number'  => ''
);

echo paginate_links( $args );
```